# JOGL 2.3.2 example compiles but fails to run (Maven in NetBeans 12.4)

Tags: java, netbeans, maven-3, jogl

On Lubuntu 21.10 and OpenJDK 16.0.2 (64bit) and Maven 3.8.2 I want to try learning `OpenGL` with `JOGL`, https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/

From here https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/ I got the `jogamp-fat-all.7z` because it is an easier start having only one jar file.

As a first example I wanted to try from here https://github.com/jvm-graphics-labs/hello-triangle the https://github.com/jvm-graphics-labs/hello-triangle/blob/master/src/main/java/gl4/HelloTriangleSimple.java

I created in `NetBeans 12.4` a `Java with Maven` project. I found on the Web a hint how to add a local jar file to the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>JOGLfirst</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
   
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jogamp-fat</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/LIBs/jogamp-fat.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I created in my project root folder a folder `LIBs` and copied the `jogamp-fat.jar` into that folder, as can be seen in my `pom.xml` how I add it as dependency.

My project structure is

```
JOGLfirst
   LIBs
      jogamp-fat.jar
   src/main/java/com/mycompany
      framework
         Semantic.java
      HelloTriangleSimple.java
```

The project compiles, but when I choose `Run File` on `HelloTraingleSimple.java` I get the following error:

```
cd /home/me/NetBeansProjects/JOGLfirst; JAVA_HOME=/home/me/PROGRAMs/openjdk-16.0.2 M2_HOME=/home/me/PROGRAMs/apache-maven-3.8.2 /home/me/PROGRAMs/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin/mvn -Dexec.vmArgs= "-Dexec.args=${exec.vmArgs} -classpath %classpath ${exec.mainClass} ${exec.appArgs}" -Dexec.executable=/home/me/PROGRAMs/openjdk-16.0.2/bin/java -Dexec.mainClass=com.mycompany.HelloTriangleSimple -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -DskipTests=true -Dexec.appArgs= org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mycompany:JOGLfirst:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.jogamp:jogamp-fat:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/LIBs/jogamp-fat.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 20, column 25

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.


    ----------------------< com.mycompany:JOGLfirst >-----------------------
    Building JOGLfirst 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    
    --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ JOGLfirst ---
    Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.HelloTriangleSimple
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opengl/GLEventListener
    Command execution failed.
    org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BUILD FAILURE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total time:  1.022 s
    Finished at: 2021-09-04T21:45:47+02:00
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project JOGLfirst: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
    
    To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    
    For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You wrote "framwork" instead of "framework".

Comment: Just an error while composing the post, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the example you use is NOT an official JogAmp example and may use some other third party libraries.

Rather do this ([it's explained in our wiki](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Maven)):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There is a better official example doing something similar [here](https://jogamp.org/cgit/jogl-demos.git/tree/src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java?id=HEAD).

I advise you to ask JOGL specific questions on our official JogAmp forum rather than here, especially if you expect a quick reply.

Comment: OK, thanks. Will try that, and also ask questions at the forum. Just a quick question: When will 2.4.0 be out, the next release?

Comment: I just tried, but another error appiears. I created a new Java with Maven project and put only the two given dependencies into the pom.xml: /home/me/PROGRAMs/openjdk-16.0.2/lib/libjawt.so: version `SUNWprivate_1.1' not found (required by /tmp/jogamp_0000/file_cache/jln6197218351352021716/jln3368270845480343845/natives/linux-amd64/libnativewindow_awt.so) I can close the post here and continue at the JogAmp forum.